# CSS: Placing one image above another in separate rows

Tags: css

I have three images numbered 1, 2 and 3.

I want to display them using CSS [like demonstrated here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXhfu.png)

I currently have them inside a `<span>` and have tried various combinations of position and float. I can get them to be display consecutively but I cannot get image 2 to be position above image 3. Here's my code:

```
<img src="1.gif" style="padding-right: 4px;"/>
<span>
     <img src="2.gif" style="float: top;">
     <img src="3.gif" style="float: bottom;">
</span>
```

Comment: There is no such a property like `float:top` in CSS

Comment: Similar to what float:top would do is `position:absolute; top:0;`. Remember to make the span `position:relative;` to prevent the image from being placed at the very top of the body.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such things as float top or bottom.
To achieve a visual like your example try this:

```
<div style="float;left">
  <img src="1.gif" style="padding-right: 4px;"/>
</div>

<div style="float:right">
  <img src="2.gif" style="display:block;">
   <img src="3.gif" style="display:block;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked to a degree: image2 is now above image3 but they are both very far away from image1. Exactly the code that you wrote is wrapped in a div, with image1 being on the far left and image2&3 on the far right.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the images to `display: block` (so they'll end up on top of one another), and float the first image to the left.

CSS:

```
.stack img {
  display: block;
}

.leftside {
  padding-right: 4px;
  float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" class="leftside"/>
<div class="stack">
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50">
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50">
</div>
```

See this in action here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/zFEjH

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to this:

```
img {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
span img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
span img:last-child {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FLTU7/